# How can I reformat a JSON file to contain an array

Tags: python, json

I have a json file `json_file` which contains 2 records:

```
{"name": "XYZ", "address": "54.7168,94.0215", "country_of_residence": "PQR", "countries": "LMN;PQRST", "date": "28-AUG-2008", "type": null}
{"name": "OLMS", "address": null, "country_of_residence": null, "countries": "Not identified;No", "date": "23-FEB-2017", "type": null}
```

How can I reformat the file using python to make it have one array like this:

```
{
    "foo" : [
       {"name": "XYZ", "address": "54.7168,94.0215", "country_of_residence": "PQR", "countries": "LMN;PQRST", "date": "28-AUG-2008", "type": null},
       {"name": "OLMS", "address": null, "country_of_residence": null, "countries": "Not identified;No", "date": "23-FEB-2017", "type": null}
    ]
}
```

Comment: Your input file is not valid JSON - JSON allows for one top-level object.

Answer (score 1):

As your json file is invalid, we need to read it line by line:

```
import json

input_file = """{"name": "XYZ", "address": "54.7168,94.0215", "country_of_residence": "PQR", "countries": "LMN;PQRST", "date": "28-AUG-2008", "type": null}
{"name": "OLMS", "address": null, "country_of_residence": null, "countries": "Not identified;No", "date": "23-FEB-2017", "type": null}"""

output_dict = dict()
output_dict['foo'] = list()

for line in input_file.split('\n'):
    json_line = json.loads(line)
    output_dict['foo'].append(json_line)
print(json.dumps(output_dict, indent=2))
```

Then we create your desired data structure, and append each line of json to that data structure.

Answer (score 1):

Your file has a JSON object on each line, which technically isn't a valid [JSON syntax](http://json.org). You can work around that by loading each line individually with `json.loads()` like this:

```
import json

json_filename = 'json_file'

with open(json_filename) as file:
    array = {'foo': []}
    foo_list = array['foo']
    for line in file:
        obj = json.loads(line)
        foo_list.append(obj)

print(json.dumps(array, indent=4))
```

```
{
    "foo": [
        {
            "name": "XYZ",
            "address": "54.7168,94.0215",
            "country_of_residence": "PQR",
            "countries": "LMN;PQRST",
            "date": "28-AUG-2008",
            "type": null
        },
        {
            "name": "OLMS",
            "address": null,
            "country_of_residence": null,
            "countries": "Not identified;No",
            "date": "23-FEB-2017",
            "type": null
        }
    ]
}
```